# Variable becomes object field in json payload when calling from other feature file

Tags: json, karate

I've got this really weird problem.

I have 2 feature files-

I am calling the dog.feature file from the cat.feature

cat.feature has the below statement-

```
def request_body = callonce read('dog.feature') {_id : #(id)}
```

The dog.feature file is act as a utility to create the json Payload

```
Scenario: xyz

* set jsonObjectPayLaod
| path         | value   |                                                                                          
| id           | _id     |                                                                                    
| name         | "xyz"   |
```

However, when I supply the id as a parameter from the first file, the id and its value is appended in the json object.

Actual Result-

```
{
  "jsonObjectPayLaod": {
    "id": 8438,
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  "_id": 8438
}
```

Expected Result-

```
  "jsonObjectPayLaod": {
    "id": 8438,
    "name": "xyz"
  }
```

I don't understand why its becoming the part of Json object.

Comment: Please have a closer look at the tools available to you in the post editor and format your code properly. Also, please don't tag your titles. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: the only way I will be able to help is if you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue